# R Shiny plotOutput cutting off labels

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R Shiny app with multiple tabs, one of which should show a barplot for the Manager selected in the select box to the left. My table has all the managers in the first column, then the rest of the columns are various metrics, with each manager having their own score/count that I want to plot.

Basically I'm selecting a Manager from a select box, and using that to filter out my data so that I get scores/counts across columns for that specific manager.

A sample table would be something like:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
| Manager  | scoreSpeed | scoreAccuracy | scoreSatisfaction |
+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
| Adam     |          5 |             9 |                10 |
| Bob      |          8 |             8 |                 8 |
| Caroline |          6 |             7 |                 9 |
| David    |         10 |            6. |                10 |
+----------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

However, as you can see in the screenshot below, the labels for each bar are being cutoff at the bottom for some reason.

Is there any way I can get the labels to not cutoff?

My `server` and `ui` code are attached.

```
manager <-c('Adam', 'Bob', 'Caroline', 'David')
scoreSpeedlongversion <- c(5,8,6,10)
scoreAccuracylongversion <- c(9,8,7,6)
scoreSatisfactionlongversion <- c(10,8,9,10)
df<-data.frame(manager,scoreSpeedlongversion, scoreAccuracylongversion, scoreSatisfactionlongversion)

ui<- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("MTM and Managers"),
    
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("selected_month", 
                    "Select Month:", 
                     choices = month_list
                    ),
        
        uiOutput("selectmanager")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Individual Table", tableOutput("individual")),
                    tabPanel("Manager Summary Table", tableOutput("manager")),
                    tabPanel("Manager Summary Bar Graph", plotOutput('managerBar'))
                    
                  
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
 #some extraneous code omitted
    reactive_manager_graph <- reactive({
        counts<-subset(reactive_manager_sums(), Manager == input$manager_selection
                       #filter out manager table so that only the selected manager is used for barplot
                       )
    })
    
    output$counts <- renderTable(reactive_manager_graph())
    
    output$managerBar <- renderPlot(
        barplot(as.matrix(reactive_manager_graph()), las=2
               )
    )
    
    
    
    output$selectmanager <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "manager_selection", 
                           label="Select Manager", 
                           choices = unique(reactive_manager_sums()$Manager)
        )
    })
    
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have more chance to get an answer if you use sample data (random, iris, cars...) to make your code reproducible

Comment: Sample table attached! Not sure if I can use a made-up table, but that's generally what it looks like.

Comment: It's better, but I still can't reproduce your issue in 2 clics. Just use a simple `df <- data.frame(...)` to include data in your code and make sure it works on its own (Restart R)

Comment: Hmmm I have that table as a `data.frame` now, although it's not the original since there's some information I'd rather keep anonymous

Comment: `Error in hasGroups(choices) : object 'month_list' not found`

Comment: Please Restart R before testing your question